# VB program guidance

Tags: database, vb.net

I am trying to create a program that will have a form to add users with multiple information (first/last name,tel,vat,email etc.) and store them in a database.

Then I want to have a standard form and will choose from the database the user each time I want to print the form. This way when the user is chosen all fields will be filled with the info from the database.

I have no clue with VB at all so all I ask here is for some guidance.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe an introductory tutorial on VB would be a good place to start?  Stack Overflow doesn't really offer tutoring services.

Comment: Hello, yes that would be great. I am not asking for tutoring, sorry I misleaded you. I want someone that knows about VB to point me to the right direction, meaning maybe a great site to start reading for example.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to learn .NET first, so head over the Microsoft Virtual Academy and wade through [VB Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/vb-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners).

If you are interested in making a user **website**, then [this Microsoft tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs) is a good place to start. It shows how to create a Movie database with maintenance screens. You should be able to adapt it to "users".

You can also search the MSDN [Developer Code Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/).

Happy coding.

*P.S. Stack Overflow is for specific technical questions, not general inquiries. That's why your question is getting down-voted.*